# Periodic Non-Autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

[image]

So when I attempted this, I thought that showing that the antiderivative of p(z) would cancel out since due to it being periodic, p(T) would equal p(0). I then tried to solve the equation of x'(t) but don't know how to connect either part so now I feel like none of it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The solution to the differential equation is

$$x(t) = x_0e^{\int_0^t p(z)dz}$$

by the integrating factor method.